# How to use a custom Parameter with SqlDataSource

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource, asp.net-webcontrol

I want to add a `GridView` control to one of my views that is backed by a `SqlDataSource`. The `SelectCommand` query is parametrized on the `aspnet_Users.UserId` GUID for the currently-logged-in user, so I need a way to pass the user ID as a parameter.

I read [How to utilize ASP.NET current user name in SqlParameter without code-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1574554/196844) and decided to create a custom [`Parameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.parameter.aspx) named `UserIdParameter`:

```
namespace MyApp.Web
{
    public class UserIdParameter : Parameter
    {
        public UserIdParameter(string name)
            : base(name)
        {
        }

        protected UserIdParameter(UserIdParameter parameter)
            : base(parameter)
        {
        }

        protected override Parameter Clone()
        {
            return new UserIdParameter(this);
        }

        protected override object Evaluate(HttpContext context, Control control)
        {
            return Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
        }
    }
}
```

In the ASPX view I then added:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="my" Namespace="MyApp.Web" %>
```

in a line after the `<%@ Page ... %>` line as well as:

```
    <SelectParameters>
        <my:UserIdParameter Name="UserId" />
    </SelectParameters>
```

within the `asp:SqlDataSource` element.

Unfortunately I get a Parser Error ("An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.") with the following highlighted in red:

```
        <my:UserIdParameter Name="UserId" />
```

Visual Web Developer 2010 Express is also informing me that "Element 'UserIdParameter' is not a known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in the Web site, or the web.config file is missing."

Do I need to modify `Web.config` in some way? If not, what do I need to do to be able to use my custom `UserIdParameter` parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The custom `UserIdParameter` class needed to be in a separate assembly and it needed a no-arguments constructor.

The steps that worked for me were:

1. Create a new ASP.NET Server Control project and add it to the current solution. (I named this new project MyApp.Web.UI.WebControls).
2. Add the following class:

   ```
   using System.Web;
   using System.Web.Security;
   using System.Web.UI;
   using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

   namespace MyApp.Web.UI.WebControls
   {
       public class UserIdParameter : Parameter
       {
           public UserIdParameter()
           {
           }

           public UserIdParameter(UserIdParameter userIdParameter)
               : base(userIdParameter)
           {
           }

           protected override Parameter Clone()
           {
               return new UserIdParameter(this);
           }

           protected override object Evaluate(HttpContext context, Control control)
           {
               return Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Build the MyApp.Web.UI.WebControls assembly. Reference it from the ASP.NET web project (named MyApp.Web in my case).
4. Add to `Web.config`:

   ```
   <pages>
         <controls>
           <add tagPrefix="my" assembly="MyApp.Web.UI.WebControls" namespace="MyApp.Web.UI.WebControls"/>
         </controls>
         <!-- ... -->
   </pages>
   ```

   This registers the controls library site-wide. (Note that the `pages` element is within the `system.web` element.)
5. Use the following in the `SelectParameters` element of the `SqlDataSource`:

   ```
   <my:UserIdParameter Name="UserGuid" DbType="Guid" />
   ```

   (No need for `<%@ Register ... %>`)

Comment: Could use explain `public UserIdParameter(UserIdParameter userIdParameter)
            : base(userIdParameter)`

Comment: @irfandar: That is a [base constructor call](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12052/196844) for calling the [Parameter(Parameter) copy constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fffwa5h.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Why did you don't use SQLDataSource with the parameters in your query ? after that i'm pretty sure that you can tell the SQLDataSource that the parameter @UserId is equal to an session variable. all that without one code line. all in the graphical interface.

Comment: As explained at [Accessing and Updating Data in ASP.NET: Creating Custom Parameter Controls](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/110106-1.aspx) in the "Determining the Currently Logged On User's UserId" section, "there is no built-in `Parameter` control that returns the currently logged in user's UserId value".

Comment: try something like this "SELECT * FROM TEST_TALBE WHERE TEST_FIELD=@TEST". the datasource component will show you a window which you'll be able to tel the datasource where it should take the value for the parameters.

Comment: SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE TEST_FIELD= @TEST">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:SessionParameter DefaultValue="asdsad" Name="TEST" SessionField="asdasd" />
        </SelectParameters>

Comment: Christophe: I don't have the GUI for configuring this. I am using Visual Web Developer 2010 Express.

Answer (score 0):

A more simpler way  is to use "Selecting" event. here you can add your custom parameter.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selecting.aspx