# Pass parameter value to SqlDataSource ASP.NET User.Identity.Name

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameter-passing, sqldatasource

Need help! I can't get around why this doesn't work.

Page:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SelectUserInfo" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TradeRelay %>" SelectCommand="admin_userinfo" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
<SelectParameters>
<asp:ControlParameter Name="suser" Type="String" DefaultValue="Anonymous" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

CodeBehind:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SelectUserInfo.SelectParameters["suser"].DefaultValue = User.Identity.Name;
}
```

Error:

> *Could not find control 'suserParam' in ControlParameter 'suser'*

UPD:

```
ControlID="suserParam"
```

was wrong! Thanks!

Comment: You're instructing the `ControlParameter` to find its value on a control with the ID = `suserParam` - and that's what it's complaining about - it cannot find that control you've defined here....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are using `ControlParameter` which extracts the parameter value from the control existing on the page. So in this case, it is trying to find control with id `suserParam` and raising error as it is unable to find it.

Try using plain parameter (`asp:Parameter`) instead of ControlParameter. Yet another alternative is using `SessionParameter` or writing your own custom parameter (see this SO question: [How to utilize ASP.NET current user name in SqlParameter without code-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574554/how-to-utilize-asp-net-current-user-name-in-sqlparameter-without-code-behind))

Comment: Thank you! <asp:Parameter Name="suser" Type="String" DefaultValue="Anonymous" /> Works!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to add `Hiddenfield` control and assign the `User.Identity.Name` to it then make the `SelectUserInfo` get the parameter value from the `Hiddenfield` control

by the way, in your code i didn't find any control with the name `suserParam`

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="suserParam"/>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SelectUserInfo" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TradeRelay %>" SelectCommand="admin_userinfo" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
<SelectParameters>
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="suserParam" Name="suser" Type="String" DefaultValue="Anonymous" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

this is the code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    suserParam.value = User.Identity.Name;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! 'suserParam' was my bad.

Answer (score -1):

You can include it directly as a standard Parameter:

```
<asp:Parameter Name="suserParam" Type="String" DefaultValue="<%=User.Identity.Name %>" />
```