# get currently logged in username asp.net without c#

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm working on a school project (so security isn't an issue) that requires me to get the name of the currently logged in user (to use as an argument for an SQL query for a `datagrid`)

Since the SQL query for the `datagrid` binding is stored in the `aspx` file, I can't use `User.Identity.Name.ToString()` like I would if this were in my c# file.

I am using the Microsoft authentication system that comes pre-built in visual studio asp.net webforms

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.filterexpression.aspx) of SQL Data-source.

Try using plain parameter (`asp:Parameter`). Yet another alternative is using `SessionParameter` or writing your own custom parameter (see this SO question: [How to utilize ASP.NET current user name in SqlParameter without code-behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574554/how-to-utilize-asp-net-current-user-name-in-sqlparameter-without-code-behind))

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the following in the ASPX file:

```
 <%=HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name %>
```

You obviously won't need the tags if you are plugging it into an existing code block...

Comment: I will try that as well, seems very straightforward and simple